# Bootstrap class.active function with Flask

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, flask

I am playing around with Flask and Bootstrap. I have my nav setup as nav-tabs and am trying to get the active class set to the active tab. It works for a split second when the link is first clicked but then immediately reverts to it's default state. I'm a bit at a loss here and any explanation as to what/why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my layout.html.

```
<body>
<div id="container-fluid">
    <nav role="navigation">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="{{url_for('index') }}" title="Home">Home</a></li>
            <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="#" title="Projects">Projects</a></li>
            <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="{{ url_for('about') }}" title="About">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="static/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('.nav li a').on("click", function(e) {
    $(".nav li").removeClass("active");
    if (!$(this).parent().hasClass("active")) {
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");
    }
    /*e.preventDefault();*/
});
</script>
```

Comment: When someone clicks a link, you send them to a new page and don't set your active class in the new page's HTML.

Comment: The last script in the code I posted does actually change the class. As I stated I can that it changes the class for a split second, but then it all changes back to default almost like it's loading the layout.html template twice

Comment: Your JavaScript runs on the original page. As soon as the browser loads the new page, the state is forgotten.

Comment: How can I get around that since I am using this html code here as the template that all other pages extend?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your route method, include a variable to tell the template rendering what page the user is on.

```
@app.route('/somepage')
def some_page():
    return render_template('somepage.html', page='somepage')
```

and in the HTML, have a conditional check if the page is the current page:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li role="presentation" {% if page == 'index' %}class="active"{% endif %}><a href="{{url_for('index') }}" title="Home">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" {% if page == 'projects' %}class="active"{% endif %}><a href="#" title="Projects">Projects</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" {% if page == 'about' %}class="active"{% endif %}><a href="{{ url_for('about') }}" title="About">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: There is no need to add the `page` to the template context. Inside the template you can just access `request.endpoint` and use that instead. For example, `{% if request.endpoint == 'some_page' %}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a **jquery/jinja-hack**. Setup ids for the elements that are the same as the apps endpoints. Like so:

```
<body>
<div id="container-fluid">
  <nav role="navigation">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li id="home" role="presentation" class=""><a href="{{url_for('index') }}" title="Home">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Then add this to the bottom of your base-layout template:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#{{request.endpoint}}").addClass("active"); })
</script>
```

No need for additional variables or conditional checks, only the list-element that has the same id as the endpoint is highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this like that will a little of your help.

```
@app.route("/profile")
def profile():
    page = request.args.get('page')
    return render_template('profile.html', page=page)

Then within the profile.html and tabpanel section:

<div role='tabpanel'>
  <div class='row'>
                    <ul class='nav nav-tabs' role='tablist' id='tabs'>
                            <li role='presentation' {% if page == 'index' %}class="active"{% endif %}><a href='#info' aria-controls='info' role='tab' data-toggle='tab' class='realtab'>info</a></li>
                            <li role='presentation' {% if page == 'edit' %}class="active"{% endif %}><a href='#edit' aria-controls='edit' role='tab' data-toggle='tab'>edit</a></li>
                            <li role='presentation' {% if page == 'messages' %}class="active"{% endif %}><a href='#messages' aria-controls='messages' role='tab' data-toggle='tab'>messages<span class='badge'>1</span></a></li>
                            <li role='presentation' {% if page == 'change_password' %}class="active"{% endif %}><a href='#change_password' aria-controls='change_password' role='tab' data-toggle='tab'>change_password</a></li>
                            <li><a href='/logout'>logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
  </div>
Further down within tab-content section:
            <div class='tab-content'>
                    <div role='tabpanel' class='tab-pane {{ 'active' if page == 'info' else '' }}' id='info'>
                    [...]
                    <div role='tabpanel' class='tab-pane {{ 'active' if page == 'edit' else '' }}' id='edit'>
                    [...]
                    <div role='tabpanel' class='tab-pane {{ 'active' if page == 'messages'  else '' }}' id='messages'>
                    [...]
                    <div role='tabpanel' class='tab-pane {{ 'active' if page == 'change_password' else '' }}' id='change_password'>

Finally at the bottom of the page:
<script>
{% if page == 'info' %}
$('#tabs li:eq(0) a').tab('show');
{% elif page == 'edit' %}
$('#tabs li:eq(1) a').tab('show');
{% elif page == 'messages' %}
$('#tabs li:eq(2) a').tab('show');
{% elif page == 'change_password' %}
$('#tabs li:eq(3) a').tab('show');
{% endif %}
</script>
```

I hope you found this useful :)